# Basic Photo Editing tool suggestions

Tags: editor, photo

Well I'm not a photographer and I'm kind of noob at editing photos. xD

I need something basic and free. Like I'll crop, resize, maybe use paint brush. Also I need blur tool so that I can blur native 'text/photo' from a screenshot. :) A couple of basic filer (for a few photos that needed to be posted in Social Media) Though it is not mandatory.

Using Ubuntu 12.04

Comment: GIMP is a powerful tool for editing photos, much like Adobe photoshop.

Comment: I suggest shutter, combine with screenshot and simple image editing function.

Answer (score 7):

## Check out [PINTA](http://pinta-project.com/)

[image]

Pinta is a free, open source drawing/editing program modeled after Paint.NET. Its goal is to provide users with a simple yet powerful way to draw and manipulate images on Linux, Mac, and Windows.

Features include:

- Adjustments (Auto level, Black and White, Sepia, …)
- Effects (Motion blur, Glow, Warp, …)
- Multiple layers
- Unlimited undo/redo
- Drawing tools (Paintbrush, Pencil, Shapes, …)
- Cropping, Cutting and Selection tools

It's available in the Software Center by clicking [**Pinta** [image: Install comixcursors-lefthanded]](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/pinta/)

Answer (score 1):

Download and try gimp from the Software Center, a full featured image editor which can do as little or as much as you want.

While a little difficult to use if you are new to it, it does what you want and has so many plug-ins it rivals Photoshop.

To install click [**Gimp** [image: Install comixcursors-lefthanded]](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/gimp/)

Comment: @Mitch Thanks for the edit. Even converting the English spelling of Centre to the American version, center ;)

Comment: You're Welcome.  We are all hear to help and learn from each other.

Comment: Well I've tried Gimp before. to be honest I like Gimp. But it is kind of for advance users. I don't usually need photo editing in my line of work. But when I need, a simple editor with 'less' options will be my saviour. Thanks for the concern! :) If I can't find something simple, then I'll head back to Gimp, I think.

Comment: In that case try Shotwell. Not good for resizing, but you can enhance and do other things with it.

Answer (score 1):

By all means try Gimp but if you want a simpler option, take a look at Fotoxx. You can blur sections, fix red eye, cut & crop, resize and quite a bit more. Nowhere near as versatile as Gimp, but much easier to use. It's in the Package Manager.

Comment: Downloading Fotoxx now. Will let you know.

Comment: Tried Fotoxx. Good app :) 
Its easy too. But I can't find the 'blur sections', I can blur the whole photo like this. http://screencloud.net/v/jXHx how do I blur selected blur section, or is there any plug-ins like Blur brush?